# How to solve an rvest Error that returns Character(0)

Tags: r, rvest

I am doing research about house living prices in Bogotá; however, I've had some issues trying to web scrape this web page:

https://www.metrocuadrado.com/casa/venta/usado/bogota/teusaquillo/?search=form

The data I am required to web scrape is 'post_name' 'price' 'area' 'rooms' and 'restrooms'. I am using SelectorGadget to identify the HTML path.

*I am using this code for it (Sorry if there is any mistake, I am new in this):*

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

page <- read_html("https://www.metrocuadrado.com/casa/venta/usado/bogota/teusaquillo/?search=form")
name <- page %>%  html_nodes(".card-title div") %>% html_text()
name
```

*The result in the console is:*
character(0)

*There is no information in name*

*I tried also with this one:*

```
 name <- page %>%  html_nodes("sc-dxgOiQ BSoGx") %>% html_text()
```

*And this one:*

```
 name <- page %>%  html_nodes("sc-dxgOiQ BSoGx card-title") %>% html_text()
```

*And this one:*

```
  name <- page %>%  html_nodes("#__next > div > div > div.Layout__LayoutStyled-sc-9y7jis-0.ibZBWk.page-container > div.Container-u38a83-0.jDuhNh.inner-container.container > div:nth-child(2) > div.Col-sc-14ninbu-0.lfGZKA.col-md-8.col-lg-9 > ul.Ul-sctud2-0.jyGHXP.realestate-results-list.browse-results-list > li:nth-child(1) > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > div.card-header > a > h2") %>% html_text()
```

*But in all cases the result was:*
character(0)

I don't know what is happening, I am not good with HTML language. I was reading some posts about it, in all of them, there was not a clear reason for what happened and how we can handle the problem if happens in the future.

Maybe the problem is the web page, if I copy and paste the page in the navigator, the same information doesn't appear. I am filtering the properties by houses(casas), buy used(compra usado), Teusaquillo (Bogotá D.C.).

Comment: Hi, Your question is one big mess. It is hard to go through it, so try to remove all the emojis and "pleaaaaaaase's" and "heeeelllloooo"... put your code as it should be!

Comment: You may need to use `RSelenium` to extract required info.

Comment: When you are scraping pages, not that content may be loaded in your browser after page load via javascript. When using `rvest`, R cannot run javascript. The results you get in a browser using SelectorGadget do not match what R actually sees. Make sure to view the page **source**, not the page elements to see what `read_html` can actually retrieve. If you need to run javascript to get the data, you'll need `RSelenium` as already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load up the webpage explicitly if the website is built upon Javascript. Rvest cannot get that info using `read_html()` function.
Here is a snippet which loads up Firefox and extracts the required info.

```
# load libraries
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

# open browser
selCommand <- wdman::selenium(jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.verboseLogging=true"), retcommand = TRUE)
Sys.sleep(2)
shell(selCommand, wait = FALSE, minimized = TRUE)
Sys.sleep(2)
remdr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "firefox")
Sys.sleep(10)
remdr$open()

# navigate to the link
remdr$navigate(url = 'https://www.metrocuadrado.com/casa/venta/usado/bogota/teusaquillo/?search=form')

# read page source
pgSrc <- remdr$getPageSource()
page <- read_html(pgSrc[[1]])

# extract required data
name <- page %>%  html_nodes(".card-title div") %>% html_text()
```

The output when we check are the names of Houses listed

```
> head(name)
[1] "Casa en Arriendo, Suba La Campiña, Bogotá D.C."     
[2] "Casa en Venta, Conjunto Oikos Savanna, Cajicá"      
[3] "Casa en Venta, CIUDAD 2000, Cali"                   
[4] "Casa en Venta, Palo De Agua, Cota (Incluye Siberia)"
[5] "Casa en Venta, Calahorra, Cajicá"                   
[6] "Casa en Venta, Calahorra, Cajicá"
```